# "Metamask no longer injects web3" using react box

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

I'm trying to create a project but I get this error "Metamask no longer injects web3". I'm using npm truffle unbox react. It injects web3 using https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box/blob/master/client/src/getWeb3.js

Is there something wrong with that code? I have tried to change it but with no success... What is the proper way to inject web3 for metamask?

Answer (score 0):

From [Web3.js documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/getting-started.html#):

```js
let web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8545");
```